# Execute JMeter scripts through Java

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I need to execute a set of JMeter scripts through command prompt.

The flow:

[image]

Need to perform the same through a Java code. i.e. Java program should open a command prompt and perform the above steps?

Note: Executing the flow through batch file is not an efficient option. It consumes OS memory.

Answer (score 0):

Although [it's possible to run JMeter script using Java code](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) via [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) using the code like:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine;
import org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.ReportGenerator;
import org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector;
import org.apache.jmeter.reporters.Summariser;
import org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService;
import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils;
import org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree;

import java.io.File;

public class JMeterTestRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // JMeter Engine
        StandardJMeterEngine jmeter = new StandardJMeterEngine();

        // Initialize Properties, logging, locale, etc.
        JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties("c:/path/to/your/jmeter/bin/jmeter.properties");
        JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome("c:/path/to/your/jmeter");
        JMeterUtils.initLocale();

        // Initialize JMeter SaveService
        SaveService.loadProperties();

        // Load existing .jmx Test Plan
        HashTree testPlanTree = SaveService.loadTree(new File("/path/to/your/test.jmx"));

        //add Summarizer output to get test progress in stdout like:
        // summary =      2 in   1.3s =    1.5/s Avg:   631 Min:   290 Max:   973 Err:     0 (0.00%)
        Summariser summer = null;
        String summariserName = JMeterUtils.getPropDefault("summariser.name", "summary");
        if (summariserName.length() > 0) {
            summer = new Summariser(summariserName);
        }


        // Store execution results into a .jtl file
        String logFile = "/path/to/test/result.jtl";
        ResultCollector logger = new ResultCollector(summer);
        logger.setFilename(logFile);
        testPlanTree.add(testPlanTree.getArray()[0], logger);

        // Run JMeter Test
        jmeter.configure(testPlanTree);
        jmeter.run();

        // Generate HTML Report Dashboard
        ReportGenerator generator = new ReportGenerator(logFile, null);
        generator.generate();

    }
}
```

I don't think resource footprint will be lower because an instance of [CMD](https://windowstect.com/windows-cmd-exe-command-interpreter-tutorial/) takes **much less** resources than Java runtime.

If your system cannot run JMeter tests due to high resources usage first of all check if you're following [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) and if yes and resource consumption is still high - you will have to find another machine and [run JMeter in distributed mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html).